# typescript arrow functions declaration in classes with return type

Tags: typescript, this, arrow-functions, typing

can someone explain what this function syntax is actually doing?

from https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/

```
  const toggleDrawer = (side: DrawerSide, open: boolean) => (
    event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent,
  ) => {
    if (
      event.type === 'keydown' &&
      ((event as React.KeyboardEvent).key === 'Tab' ||
        (event as React.KeyboardEvent).key === 'Shift')
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [side]: open });
  };
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

I thought the 2nd set of parens was defining the return type, as a union type, but that doesn't seem to be the case as the `event` is passed into the function below.

For example like:

```
public toggleDrawer (side: DrawerSide, open: boolean):any {
```

turning that into a class public method I think is the following:

```
  public toggleDrawer = (side: DrawerSide, open: boolean) => (
    event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent,
  ) => {
   ...
  }
```

So not clear why it doesn't use the `:return` syntax from other TS method signatures.

Is this some fancy syntax in TS with arrow functions to make sure the `this` is what we want it to be, an instance of the class?

Comment: Higher order function. The `toggleDrawer` function is returning a function of type `(event) => void`

Answer (score 1):

The code is utilizing [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) as suggested in the comment. The syntax is indeed a little fancy but the concept is pretty straight forward. They're simply functions that "takes one or more functions as arguments" and/or "returns a function as its result." Here are some examples:

```
// HO that returns a function
const first = (a: number, b: number) => {
    return () => a + b;
}
const firstHo = first(21, 21);
console.log(firstHo()); // 42

// HO that takes a function
const second = (a: number, func: (b: number, c: string) => string) => {
    console.log(func(a, "Hello World"));
}
const feed = (a: number, b: string) => `${b} : ${a}`;
second(42, feed); // Hello World : 42

//HO that takes AND returns a function
const third = (a: number, func: (b: number, c: string) => string) => {
    return (d: number) => func(a + d, "Hello World");
}
const thirdHo = third(21, feed);
console.log(thirdHo(21)); // Hello World : 42
```

I'm explicitly returning lambdas for clarity but any of these functions could be simplified into something more like yours which can be a bit harder to make sense of:

`(a: number, b: number) => () => a + b;`

The example in your link makes its use pretty clear. In the markup you'll see this:

```
onClick={toggleDrawer(side, false)}
```

Obviously, you're setting the event handler here but `toggleDrawer` *isn't* the handler; it's the function that provides the handler so this resolves to:

```
onClick={(event) => {...}}
```

As far as your question about using `:return` syntax, I can't say why the author did it that way but I assume it's for simplicity and readability. Your example fully typed with the return defined would look like this:

```
toggleDrawer = (side: DrawerSide, open: boolean) : (event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent) => 
    (event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent) => {...}
```

This just makes it cryptic while providing no additional information; it's just duplicating the next bit of code which already gives you the returned function's signature.

---

To address another (now deleted) answer: what I don't believe it's doing is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) functions which "is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument." What you may find interesting though is the function that curries another function is itself a higher-order function! Here's an overly simplistic example:

```
// add just adds three numbers
const add = (a: number, b: number, c: number) : number => a + b + c;

// curry takes a function that takes three numbers and returns a number
// and returns a series of functions that each take a single number which
// eventually calls the given function passing the three numbers in
const curry = (f: (a: number, b: number, c: number) => number) => 
    (a: number) => (b: number) => (c: number) => f(a, b, c);

const curriedAdd = curry(add);
const addOneTo = curriedAdd(1);
const addThreeTo = addOneTo(2);
const seven = addThreeTo(4);
console.log(seven); // 7
// You could also call it like so, though it makes currying pointless
console.log(curriedAdd(1)(2)(4)); // 7
```

---

Both of these techniques seem esoteric at first but they're both very powerful and you likely use one or both in your day-to-day life. For example `filter`, `map`, and `forEach` are all higher-order functions. You pass your `predicate` function into `filter` and the algorithm happily applies it to each element in your array. All `filter` cares about is that your predicate takes an element and returns a boolean value. Optionally, your predicate could be a curried function.

Comment: wow this is a great detailed answer, thanks for taking the time. I thought I saw another answer here that this was currying and NOT a HOF, but that seems to have been deleted...